# MikroTik - configure NAT behind NAT

Tags: nat, mikrotik, routeros

I have primary Mikrotik router connected to Internet provider and serving internal network 192.168.88.0/24. I also have second Mikrotik router which I want to plug into my internal network of the first router and server its own internal network. I can control both routers.

I have configured second one to serve its own internal network 192.168.77.0/24 using QuickSet, and allocated IP address for it on the first one. After this second router is visible in the list of DHCP clients on the first router with address that I've configured. Second router itself seems to have connection to Internet (it is able to find RouterOS update). However any clients connected to the second router do not have access to Internet. They successfully receive IP address from it, DNS also seems to work (i.e. for example `nslookup google.com` on the client PC gives some IP address in answer). However web browser can't open any site. `tracert` on Windows shows that packets reach router and stuck there, i.e. like

```
1 <1ms  <1ms  <1ms    192.168.77.1
2 *     *     *
```

What am I doing wrong? What need to be tuned additionally to make it working?

Comment: Seems to be similar situation https://serverfault.com/questions/670229

Comment: solved by https://serverfault.com/a/670232/152103